# How to blacklist/demote search results with certain set of keywords in ElasticSearch and Apache Solr?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, solr

I was comparing both ElasticSearch and Apache Solr for a search solution. Data that will go into the system is not moderated and I don't want anyone to search for something and some sexually explicit content to flash on the very top of the search result. But I don't want to remove them for search results either. I want to demote them, so that they come later in the search results. Can I do this in Solr or ElasticSearch ? Some pointers towards how to achieve this will be helpful.

Comment: You identify a set of words/terms that you don't want to be promoted and create a query that will: score normally the documents that match your search request and, also, maybe using 'function_score' you give a very low score (0.00001) to those documents that also match your "undesired" list of words/terms. It's all about controlling scoring.

Comment: whoever these people are, down voting a question, should also try to explain, why are they doing so. It is not really helping in any way. I'm trying to solve a problem here. It may be a trivial one for some, apparently a blocker task for me. But if you can't contribute anything positive, then you should better refrain from taking part in the discussion altogether. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Solr you can't give "negative boosts" per se but you can boost everything that doesn't have the term. This can be done with the boost query:

```
...&bq=(*:* -erotic)^999
```

or in solrconfig.xml:

```
<str name="bq">(*:* -erotic)^999</str>
```

Where "erotic" is the term to which you wish to give a "negative boost". To add another term, add another bq=....

Comment: Yes, I can do that. For one or two words, that is fine. But I will have a large list of such blacklisted words. The source will be either a text file or from Relational DB.

Comment: Perhaps you could look into creating an "explicit" field. If you have a custom indexer, you could make it check the fields in each record for blacklisted words and set the explicit field to Y or N, then boost on explicit:N. Alternately, it could contain the number of blacklisted terms found, then boosted with bf or boost.